# Is edit-and-continue supported on remote-debugging with c++ or c#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, remote-debugging

is edit-and-continue debugging supported in below platforms remotely ?

- c++ remote-debugging on windows ?
- c++ remote-debugging on Linux ?
- c#  remote-debugging on windows ?
- c#  remote-debugging on Linux with mono/dotnet core ?

Comment: You can debug C++ with `gdbserver` on Linux

Comment: First: post *one* question, not *four*. Second: Why not try it out? Anyway: would an answer such as "yes, maybe, no, no" help you at all? I suppose no. But that´s what you probably get when posting such unspecific questions. So please post an actual specific problem, not just a fictious issue.

Comment: @everyone remote debugging is supported,question is edit-and-continue supported or not,not debugging itself

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDocs, for C# I found the following information:

> Do not make changes to the code or rebuild (or you must repeat this
>   step). The executable you copied to the remote machine must exactly
>   match your local source and symbols.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp

For c++ this information is a little bit more cryptic:

> Alternatively, you can deploy the files as a separate step. In the
>   Solution Explorer, right-click the mymfc node and then choose Deploy.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp

So for my understanding this means, that there is no way around manually deploying the files to the remote machine because your local files must always match the remote file.